# Place an image into div on a page with a form after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to apply [this jQuery example](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html) with exception that my **html-echo.php** script takes post data and generates an image (Content-type: image/jpeg). I need to show the image output on the same page where form is. If I use `<div id="htmlExampleTarget">` tag as a target - I receive set of Characters like this

> ����JFIF����_�7[�'������u�����⎲<]��e�|>�w

instead of an image. If I use `<img id="htmlExampleTarget">` - it doesn't appear at all..

Please advise me how to solve this?

Comment: The plugin is designed to display text data, not the binary data of an image. Assuming the data is base64 encoded, try setting it as the `src` property of the image.

Comment: What about `base64`?

Comment: Just get the path of the image file from the html-echo.php file and set that path in jquery to the image tag. This will prevent you from all types of issues regarding encoding.

Comment: you want top use an image tag with the src set to be the url that generates the image, I would probably change your post to a get too so that you can just pass the params on the querystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening because the example you are using is designed to display the text not the image data.

It's showing it as above because image data is out of the utf-8 (or whatever you are setting on your web page) encoding

**Solution**

*On server end* 
echo the image data in base 64 encoded formate

*On client end*
Use Ajax like

```
$(document).ready( function() { 

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:'get_image_probes_via_ajax.pl',
  contentType: "image/png",
  data: "id_projet=[% visual.projet.id %]",
  success: function(data){
  $('.div_imagetranscrits').html('<img src="' + data + '" />'); },
 } );
```

Post you sample code here for more help/if it wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

If your image is saved on a directory, Hope this will work.

```
<?php 
    echo "<div style='background-color:#ffa; padding:20px'>
              <img src='path/to/image/file/image.jpg' />
          </div>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use src attribute into img tag from where you are getting that image.

Answer (score 0):

My code is:

form.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 

        target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 

        success: function() { 
            $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});

</script>

<form id="htmlForm" action="picture.php" method="post"> 
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Generate Image" /> 
</form>
<div id="htmlExampleTarget"></div>
```

picture.php

```
<?php 

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('background.jpg');

    // Manipulations with the image, text $_POST['message'] overlay, etc.

    ImageJpeg($im);

?>
```

How to encode output of picture.php? 
Should I have something like `echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'. base64_encode($im) .'" />'` at the end of picture.php ? But echo is not allowed when content type is set to image, and `$im` is not a string object..

Comment: Found a solution - add buffering at the end of picture.php - ob_start() / ob_get_contents() / ob_end_clean()